# How to interpret semivariogram with range but no partial sill?

Tags: r, spatial, gstat, geor

I have been using the variofit function in R's gstat package to fit semivariogram models to some spatial data I have, and I am confused by a couple of the models that have been generated. Basically for these few models, I will get a model that has a range for autocorrelation, but not a partial sill. I was told that even without a sill, though, the model should still have some sort of shape to reflect the range, but plotting this model results in the flat lines that are shown in the attached screenshot. I do not think it is a matter of bad initial values as I let variofit parse out the best initial values from a matrix of many values made by expand.grid. I wanted to know whether this is being plotted correctly contrary to what I've been told, and what exactly it means to have a range but no partial sill value. I know when I used an alternative model fitting function from geoR (fit.variogram), these models could be fit to a periodic or wave distribution, though poorly so/probably overfit — so would this be some indication of that, which variofit just cannot plot? I unfortunately can't share the data, but I included an example of the code I have used to make these models if it will help to answer my question:

```
geo.entPC <- as.geodata(cbind(jitteryPC, log.PC[,5], coords.col=1:2, data.col=5))

test.pc.grid2 <- expand.grid(seq(0,2,0.2),seq(0,100,10))

variog.function.col2 <-function (x) {
  vario.cloud <- variog(x, estimator.type = "classical", option="bin")
  variogram.mod <- variofit(vario.cloud , ini.cov.pars=test.pc.grid2,  fix.nug=FALSE, weights="equal")
  plot(vario.cloud)
  lines(variogram.mod, col="red")
  summary(x)
 
  
}

variog.function.col2(geo.entPC)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the attached plot showing the empirical variogram, I would not expect to find any sensible spatial correlation. This is in accordance with the fitted variogram, which is essentially a pure nugget model. The spatial range might be a relic of the numerical optimization, or the partial spatial sill might (numerically) differ from 0 at a digit that is not shown in the summary of the fitted variogram. However, no matter what the range is for an irrelevant small partial sill, **the spatial correlation is neglectable**.

Depending on the data, it is sometimes beneficial to limit the maximum distance of pairs used to calculate the empirical variogram - but make sure to have "enough" pairs in each bin.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was thinking that these would be nugget models but the range was throwing me off!